# Exporting data from function to import to another class React Native

Tags: function, react-native, import, export

I have this function in my app.js file:

```
codePush.getUpdateMetadata().then(update => {
  if (update) {
    Sentry.setVersion(update.appVersion + "-codepush:" + update.label); 
     // update.label  
  }
});
```

I want to export the value of update.label as a string and call it in another class so I can display its value on a screen. I'm new to React Native and unsure of how to do this. How do I pass it out of the function? and How to I pass it out of the class so I can import into another?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should save the label in `AsyncStorage` and when and where you want to show it, just retrieve it there from the `AsyncStorage`. You can refer [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) to get to know about the AsyncStorage in React Native.